# Flutter: How to get the microphone's raw audio signal into memory in real time?

Tags: flutter, audio

Well, the title says it all. The idea is to monitor ambient noise. As soon as a certain pattern is detected, the audio signal should be recorded to a file. The difficulty is that the recorded file should start a few seconds before the pattern is detected. Hence the audio signal is needed in memory to be able to "go back" a few seconds. Do you have any ideas how to get the raw audio input into memory in real time?

Comment: not a flutter dev but FWIW the generic proc for this is to debug/locate where the api delivers the audio buffer . The event/listener should have data type like a raw array.  With a ref to that array, within the scope of where the listener delivers audio buffer data, your process does this :   1. arrayCopy on the buffer  2. load result of number 1 to a circularBuffer where u manage/suspend your metaArray in order to maintain prior nn seconds of audio in raw form .  IMO the api should give u access prior to any encoding having been done on the raw buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the flutter sound plugin to get the microphone's raw audio signal into memory in real-time.
reference link is:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound
and demo example is here https://github.com/dooboolab/flutter_sound/blob/master/example/lib/demo_util/demo3_body.dart

I have one example is

```
Widget _buildRecorder(Track track) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: RecorderPlaybackController(
            child: Column(
          children: [
            Left("Recorder"),
            SoundRecorderUI(track),
            Left("Recording Playback"),
            SoundPlayerUI.fromTrack(
              track,
              enabled: false,
              showTitle: true,
              audioFocus: true
                  ? AudioFocus.requestFocusAndDuckOthers
                  : AudioFocus.requestFocusAndDuckOthers,
            ),
          ],
        )));
  }

}
```

Comment: Seems like flutter_sound was updated just right on time. Recording into streams is supported since version 6.0, which was just released the day before yesterday (23rd of Sep). Anyway, thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 1):

The [sound_stream](https://pub.dev/packages/sound_stream) package can help you stream microphone audio as a `Stream<Uint8List>` in PCM format. Assuming that you have, 16000 samples per second, you can use this to create a stream that yields *n* second audio chunks:

```
import 'dart:math'; // for min
import 'dart:typed_data'; // for Uint8List
import 'package:sound_stream/sound_stream.dart';

Stream<Uint8List> audioChunks([int seconds = 3]) async* {
  final stream = RecorderStream();
  await stream.initialize();
  stream.start();

  BytesBuilder buffer = BytesBuilder();
  int filled = 0;
  int max = seconds * 16000 * 2; // pcm 16bit = 2bytes / sample

  await for (final chunk in stream.audioStream) {
    int cl = min(max-filled, chunk.length);
    buffer.add(chunk.sublist(0, cl));
    filled += cl;
    if (filled == max) {
      yield buffer.toBytes();
      filled = 0;
      buffer.clear();
    }
    if (chunk.length > cl) {
      buffer.add(chunk.sublist(cl));
      filled += chunk.length - cl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Its a GPL package though.